# How to electric motors work?

Tags: power-supply, motor, stepper-motor, stepper-driver, rotor-speed

I’m planning on building a electric bike/motorcycle and was wondering on what affects motor speed and torque.

1. How does voltage affect a brushed motor and brushless motor?
2. I would be powering this off a battery pack, if the max discharge amperage is 30A, how do I prevent the motor from drawing more than that?
3. If I have a 48V motor and supply a power source of 48V 20Ah, how do I know how much amperage it will draw?
4. If I want fast acceleration, can I somehow give more amperage than reduce the amperage and increase volts for top speed?
5. How do Tesla’s achieve such fast acceleration with no gearbox?

I’m sorry those are long questions. Any help on any question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question really is too general. Particularly troublesome is #4, since there is indication that you do not understand how voltage and current work (you can't reduce amperage without reducing voltage and you can't increase voltage without increasing amperage). Those are issues that should be done in some basic reading first. Then you can come back and ask some more specific questions.

Comment: What type of battery pack are you using?

Comment: Re 5, check out the motor torque curve.

Comment: Motor speed is set by effective applied voltage. If you apply a higher voltage, the motor will try to go faster. The Kv parameter of the motor will give you a rough idea of how fast the motor will spin. You multiply the Kv * battery voltage to get an estimate of max RPM you can achieve. The estimate will always be higher than what you really get. The motor controller, basically, uses PWM to apply a lower voltage than the battery voltage. But it can't really ever apply a higher voltage. So matching battery voltage and Kv is important.

Answer (score 1):

1. Brushed motors can run without a controller, higher voltage will allow them to run faster, a BLDC motor has to be used with a controller and that determines the speed, while the voltage determins the maximum speed possible.
2. By using a BMS and also setting a max current limit in the BLDC controller.
3. Depends on the BLDC controller, you set the max power limits in it.
4. Voltage and current dont work aganist each other, you can have both if your BLDC is correctly matched to your battery and controller and big enough.
5. It has a gearbox, just not with adjustable ratio, electric motors have insane low speed torque.

There is a lot to learn about BLDC motors, so i would recommend getting a small motor and a good controller and trying different scenarios to better understand how to properly control them.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I understand what I need to know to start a project.

Comment: Also to clarify number 4, I meant using a converter that will lower voltage and increase amperage if that would increase torque, similar to power line transformers.

Comment: You are probably more limited by the motor than battery current

Comment: Brushed  motors can run without a controller, but not in an electric vehicle. Vehicles other than the most simple and slow types, require some type of speed control.

Answer (score 1):

Basically voltage limits speed and current limits torque.  whichever you run out of first will limit your vehicle's performance accordingly.